# mobile/sm breakpoint not working in my Tailwindcss project

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I am working on a Nextjs + Tailwindcss project, where I am facing some screen responsiveness issues.

In my project, every tailwind breakpoint is working fine except "sm" and below that.

Here is my example code:

```
<div className="bg-red-200 sm:bg-white md:bg-gray-700 lg:bg-green-600 xl:bg-blue-600">
```

with the above code, if I rescale my screen in inspect mode, every breakpoint from xl to md is working. but below md, I am not able to see any change.

Here is my globas.css file:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

* {
  cursor: none;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Neue Montreal";
    src: url("/fonts/NeueMontreal-Regular.otf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Neue Montreal Bold";
    src: url("/fonts/NeueMontreal-Bold.otf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Neue Montreal Light";
    src: url("/fonts/NeueMontreal-Light.otf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Neue Montreal Medium";
    src: url("/fonts/NeueMontreal-Medium.otf");
}

body {
  font-family: Neue Montreal, sans-serif;
}
```

& my tailwind.config.js file:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

I tried to look into multiple resources but none of them helped me, please help me fix this issue, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see any issue with your code. I've recreated the same on on CSB and it works as intended.

https://codesandbox.io/s/using-tailwind-with-next-js-forked-ue6ts2

Maybe you can try to inspect the div while resizing the screen to see if the media query shows up correctly in each breakpoints. Also, try to remove your node_modules and reinstall the packages. sometimes that fixes the problem

Comment: Hey @Idris, thanks for your help but removing & reinstalling node modules didn't help me out. but after your suggestion when I looked into inspect window, I found some specificity issues. below md: properties are crossed-out, and I am not sure by what.

Comment: Okay now we’re getting somewhere. So if you found out the sm is crossed out, find which style is currently active and overwriting the sm. then you’ll know what is the culprit @GouravKumar

Comment: I looked into it bro, it turns out the md-screen is overriding the sm-screen. I tried multiple ways to fix it but nothing worked, then I decided to reset the project and now everything works, idk it's a package issue or what I haven't faced that issue since then, even though everything is the same (as per my knowledge).

Comment: I highly suspect its a package issue. Glad it’s solved!